# T-SQL: Paging WITH TIES

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to implement a paging routine that's a little different.

For the sake of a simple example, let's assume that I have a table defined and populated as follows:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    ParentId    INT,
    [TimeStamp] DATETIME,
    Value       INT
);

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, '1/1/2013 00:00', 6);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, '1/1/2013 01:00', 7);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, '1/1/2013 02:00', 8);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2, '1/1/2013 00:00', 6);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2, '1/1/2013 01:00', 7);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2, '1/1/2013 02:00', 8);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3, '1/1/2013 00:00', 6);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3, '1/1/2013 01:00', 7);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3, '1/1/2013 02:00', 8);
```

`TimeStamp` will always be the same interval, e.g. daily data, 1 hour data, 1 minute data, etc. It will not be mixed.

For reporting and presentation purposes, I want to implement paging that:

1. Orders by `TimeStamp`
2. Starts out using a suggested `pageSize` (say 4), but will automatically adjust to include additional records matching on `TimeStamp`. In other words, if 1/1/2013 01:00 is included for one `ParentId`, the suggested `pageSize` will be overridden and all records for hour 01:00 will be included for all `ParentId's`. It's almost like the `TOP WITH TIES` option.

So running this query with `pageSize` of 4 would return 6 records. There are 3 hour 00:00 and 1 hour `01:00` by default, but because there are more hour `01:00's`, the `pageSize` would be overridden to return all hour `00:00` and `01:00`.

Here's what I have so far, and I think I'm close as it works for the first iteration, but sequent queries for the next `pageSize+` rows doesn't work.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ParentId, [TimeStamp], Value,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) AS rnk,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) AS rownum
    FROM @Temp
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE (rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 4) OR (rnk BETWEEN 1 AND 4)
ORDER BY TimeStamp, ParentId
```

The ROW_NUMBER ensures the minimum pageSize is met, but the RANK will include additional ties.

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned that I was using 2008.

Comment: you should use a condition on timestamp. For the first query `timestamp > minValue` (depending on your column type datetime or datetime2). From the result of the query you read a max value for time stamp. For the following query you use this max to filter: `select top 4 with ties * from @temp where timestamp > max`

Comment: @tschmit007, thanks for the reply. perhaps i'm trying to go about this in a bad way, maybe i should make my predicate around timestamp instead of rownum and rank. i will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your strategy of  using `row_number()` and `rank()` is overcomplicating things.

Just pick the top 4 timestamps from the data.  Then choose any timestamps that match those:

```
select *
from @temp
where [timestamp] in (select top 4 [timestamp] from @temp order by [TimeStamp])
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing. Using row_number and rank made it much more difficult. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Temp as Table ( ParentId Int, [TimeStamp] DateTime, [Value] Int );
insert into @Temp ( ParentId, [TimeStamp], [Value] ) values
 (1, '1/1/2013 00:00', 6),
 (1, '1/1/2013 01:00', 7),
 (1, '1/1/2013 02:00', 8),
 (2, '1/1/2013 00:00', 6),
 (2, '1/1/2013 01:00', 7),
 (2, '1/1/2013 02:00', 8),
 (3, '1/1/2013 00:00', 6),
 (3, '1/1/2013 01:00', 7),
 (3, '1/1/2013 02:00', 8);

declare @PageSize as Int = 4;
declare @Page as Int = 1;

with Alpha as (
    select ParentId, [TimeStamp], Value,
        Rank() over ( order by [TimeStamp] ) as Rnk,
        Row_Number() over ( order by [TimeStamp] ) as RowNum
    from @Temp ),
    Beta as (
    select Min( Rnk ) as MinRnk, Max( Rnk ) as MaxRnk
        from Alpha
        where ( @Page - 1 ) * @PageSize < RowNum and RowNum <= @Page * @PageSize )
    select A.*
        from Alpha as A inner join
            Beta as B on B.MinRnk <= A.Rnk and A.Rnk <= B.MaxRnk
        order by [TimeStamp], ParentId;
```

**EDIT**:
An alternative query that assigns page numbers as it goes, so that next/previous page can be implemented without overlapping rows:

```
with Alpha as (
    select ParentId, [TimeStamp], Value,
        Rank() over ( order by [TimeStamp] ) as Rnk,
        Row_Number() over ( order by [TimeStamp] ) as RowNum
    from @Temp ),
    Beta as (
    select ParentId, [TimeStamp], Value, Rnk, RowNum, 1 as Page, 1 as PageRow
        from Alpha
        where RowNum = 1
    union all
    select A.ParentId, A.[TimeStamp], A.Value, A.Rnk, A.RowNum,
        case when B.PageRow >= @PageSize and A.TimeStamp <> B.TimeStamp then B.Page + 1 else B.Page end,
        case when B.PageRow >= @PageSize and A.TimeStamp <> B.TimeStamp then 1 else B.PageRow + 1 end
        from Alpha as A inner join
            Beta as B on B.RowNum + 1 = A.RowNum
     )
    select * from Beta
        option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

Note that recursive CTEs often scale poorly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but PageSize = 1 and 2, both return hour 01:00 data.

Comment: @JohnRussell - It's working for me in SS 2008 R2.  With a page size of 1, pages 1, 2 and 3 return the same set of midnight data.  Pages 4, 5 and 6 return the set of 1am data.  You can change the final `select` to either `select * from Alpha` or `select * from Beta` to see what is going on.

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is that pages overlap. Page n starts on the record after (n-1)*pagesize regardless if previous pages were larger than the specified pagesize.

Comment: @ChadHenderson - My intent was to select rows strictly based on the page and page size, then to extend the rows returned to cover rows with matching timestamps either before or after.  The OP has a problem with the Principle Of Least Surprise.  Should "next page"/"previous page" always display non-overlapping data to the user?  If a user skips to page 15, should that be based solely on page size or incorporate skipping duplicate `TimeStamp` values?  If there happens to be a large number of duplicate `TimeStamp` values is it reasonable to return a page with 666 rows?

Comment: @JohnRussell - The second query assigns page numbers on the fly.  It works for small samples, but I suspect that large numbers of rows will slow it down.  Note that you can tweak the recursion to stop when the desired page number is exceeded.

Comment: @HABO - I was just trying to interpret the OP's requirements. My personal opinion is that you wouldn't want pages to overlap, particularly when navigating next/previous. But of course, it's important to weigh the cost and complexity of a solution against the benefit it offers.

Comment: Nice! I had been trying to figure out how to do it with a recursive CTE, but I couldn't get there. Now the only problem is that you'll exceed the max recursion depth if there are more than 100 items :)

Comment: @ChadHenderson - Fixed with the addition of `option ( MaxRecursion 0 )`.  I always forget that.